# How to disable a button in angular 2 and then enable it once the data loads

Tags: angular2-forms

I have a form with save button.Once the data is loaded in the form then only I need to enable the save button.

How to disable a button in angular 2? This might sound simple.

Things I tried

1 - `[disabled]="true"` but it does not work.

2 - `[disabled]="!isValid"` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the button on the template like:

```
<button [disabled]="disableButton">Send</button>
```

Then on your component declare the variable:

```
disableButton = true;
```

When your data is loaded you simply activate the button:

```
this.disableButton = false;
```

Comment: The application has tons of components,css,html so to figure out where to change is the most difficult task.Also the UI is config driven.

Comment: You have to decide the point where you want to enable your button and there to modify your disableButton variable from true to false and to pass it to your component that contains the button.